# How to run a single Test method using Multiple instances of Browsers | OS one after the other with TestNG?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
<test name="Test chrome on windows 7">
  <parameter name="test-title"  value="chrome with video"/>
  <parameter name="browser-name"  value="chrome"/>
  <parameter name="platform-name"  value="WIN7"/>
  <parameter name="browser-version"  value=""/>
   <classes> 
      <class name="demo.test" />   
    </classes>
  </test>      

  <test name="Test chrome on windows 8">
  <parameter name="test-title"  value="FF with video"/>
  <parameter name="browser-name"  value="firefox"/>
  <parameter name="platform-name"  value="WIN8"/>
  <parameter name="browser-version"  value=""/>
   <classes> 
      <class name="demo.test" />   
    </classes>
  </test>

@BeforeMethod
public void beforeMethod(String browser_name, String platform_name, String browser_version) throws Exception {
}

@Test
public void test_login() throws Exception  {         
.................
}
```

**P.S|** I used only one Test Method here; Generally when we run a test, it automatically starts all the mentioned browsers from the xml file at the same or with little delay. What I expect is to open each browser one after the other when the test is gets over.

Comment: you want to run same test method on diff platforms?? the question is bit confusing..can you be specific pls

Comment: I'm running the same test on diff platforms and I don't want them to run parallely. Hope you got it..

Comment: AFAIK ...Using testNG you can impose dependency on same platform to run in sequence ...but not different platforms. Would love..if it's possible.

Comment: @Anuragh27crony I purposely run on different platforms :)